# Deploying Application that use SWI-Prolog without installing SWI-Prolog

Tags: visual-studio-2012, swi-prolog, vspackage

I create a VS-Package application (.vsix) that uses SWI-Prolog inside it.

My question is: how can I deploy my VS-Package application (VS 2012) without requiring the user the run the SWI-Prolog installer? Is it possible for me to just create a folder in my client computer and copy some SWI-Prolog libraries in there?

Thanks

Comment: have you read the [docs](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%281,%2710%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/runtime.html%27%29%29) ?

Comment: Hi CapeliC. I read it, but still cannot get how can I actually solve my problem. Can you give me more clue? Note: my application is not purely built from SWI-Prolog. I use SWI-Prolog inside a VS-2012 Package application.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't have VS2012, then cannot say nothing about the details, neither start a test case. AFAIK the *manifest* was the mean to configure executable code locations, but was of little use in practical setting I had in the past.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=saved-states) it's a case of saving the state and passing the emulator in:

`swipl -o mystate --stand_alone=true -c myload.pl`

The --Options are passed to qsave_program/2, so the possible values are discussed in the link if you need more customisation. [A docs example, also worth a read](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=cmdlinecomp)